# jquery mobile tabs not to show on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a page with tabs I don't want the div to show when page is loaded only when it is clicked

```
     <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs" >
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="1" href="#one" data-ajax="false">1</a></li>
      <li><a id="2" href="#two" data-ajax="false">2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I used this to hide the tab:

```
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("div#one").hide();
        }); 
    </script>
```

The problem is if I try to open the first tab, nothing happens. I think its already opened. (first tab works fine after click on `#two`) 
Is there a way to set the tabs to don't show on load?

edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/b9bafuu4/6/

 tab 1 show as page load id like non of them to show up when the page load

Comment: please provide us with a jsfiddle so our help can be more oriented to your problem. also ... make a better description of your problem ... thanks

Comment: added jsfiddle :) sry forgat about it

Comment: did you try to add the display:none; css rule to the element(s) you want to hide? I can't see what you intend by looking at the fiddle ... you want to display the tabs on load but not the tab content?

Comment: no the tabs are filters options for the rest of the page i dont want any of them to show till the tab is clickt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? see here -> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/b9bafuu4/7/)

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('[href="#one"]').click(function(){
        $('#one > ul').css('display','block');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#one > ul{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: well allmost like i wanted the rest of the page seem to still get push down like the div is there : http://jsfiddle.net/b9bafuu4/5/

Comment: edited the answer ... see the affected changes and if that is what you intended ... keep in mind that you need to ask all your doubts in the OP in order to have the proper help from the community.

Comment: this still go down one line but i can live with that thx alot :) sry for the bad english/explanation